LuaSnip VScode snippets for Apex not showing
In Neovim I tried adding my own VSCode style snippets for Apex programming language to LuaSnip and I can't get it to work.
This is my packer.lua file:
vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]

return require('packer').startup(function(use)
    
    -- [...]

    use {
        'VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim',
        branch = 'v3.x',
        requires = {
            {'williamboman/mason.nvim'},
            {'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim'},
            {'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'},
            {'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'},
            {'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp'},
            {'L3MON4D3/LuaSnip'},
        }
    }
end)


This is my after/plugin/lsp.lua where I configure the LSP:
local lsp_zero = require('lsp-zero')

lsp_zero.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
    lsp_zero.default_keymaps({buffer = bufnr})
end)

local capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities()

local servers = {
    apex_ls = {
        filetypes = {
            'apexcode',
            'apex',
            'soql',
            'sosl',
        }
    },
    lwc_ls = {
        filetypes = {
            'javascript',
            'html',
            'js-meta.xml'
        },
    },
    lua_ls = {
        settings = {
            Lua = {
                completion = {
                    callSnippet = 'Replace',
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

    require('mason').setup({})
    require('mason-lspconfig').setup({
        handlers = {
            function(server_name)
                local server = servers[server_name] or {}
                server.capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend('force', {}, capabilities, server.capabilities or {})
                require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup(server)
            end,
        },
    })

    local cmp = require('cmp')
    local cmp_select = {behavior = cmp.SelectBehavior.Select}
    
    require("luasnip.loaders.from_vscode").lazy_load() -- LuaSnip
    cmp.setup({
        preselect = 'item',
        completion = {
            completeopt = 'menu,menuone,noinsert'
        },
        expand = function(args)
            require('luasnip').lsp_expand(args.body)
        end,
        mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
            ['<C-p>'] = cmp.mapping.select_prev_item(cmp_select),
            ['<C-n>'] = cmp.mapping.select_next_item(cmp_select),
            ['<C-y>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }),
            ['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
        }),
        sources = cmp.config.sources({
            { name = 'nvim_lsp' },
            { name = 'luasnip' },
        }, {
            { name = 'buffer' },
        }),
        window = {
            completion = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
            documentation = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
        },
    })

And for the snippets
Those are some of my snippets in ~/.config/nvim/snippets/apex.json:
{
    "for": {
        "prefix": "for",
        "body": [
            "for (${1:type} ${2:variable} : ${3:Iterable}) {",
            "\t$0",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": "standard for loop"
    },
    "fori": {
        "prefix": "fori",
        "body": [
            "for (Integer i${1:i} = 0; i${1:i} < ${2:end}; i${1:i} ++) {",
            "\t$0",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": "for i loop"
    },
}

and this is my ~/.config/nvim/package.json:
{
    "name": "my-nvim-config",
    "contributes": {
        "snippets": [
            {
                "language": [
                    "apex"
                ],
                "path": "snippets/apex.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}

The luasnip works in .lua files, I get the snippets 
but when I try in apex file I don't get any snippets, just LSP suggestions. 
I already tried

like in this example from LuaSnip doc
like this comment suggests (current version)
changing language in package.json from apex to all

but noting works, I can't get any Apex snippets.
Also, there is nothing in luasnip.log file and when I execute command :LspInfo I get correctly detected file type (Detected filetype:   apex) and when I execute :LuaSnipListAvailable I get my snippets list
{                                                                                                                                                                                            
  all = {},                                                                                                                                                                                   
  apex = { { 
    ...
  }
}

I've been looking through the documentation, github issues, reddit, blogposts etc. for a long time now and have been trying a lot of different configuration options but I'm pretty new to neovim so it's kind of blind copying and pasting someone else's code and seeing what happens. I feel like I'm going too deep into this and that the problem might be somewhere else, if anyone could at least point me in the right direction that would be a huge help.

You might try How to debug my vimrc and How to navigate :help. Blindly copy-pasting is generally just going to be a bad idea—it's much harder to debug, as you're experiencing. I would recommend taking a step back and making sure you understand the code you use for your editor.
